# Change Chrome Omnibox to use Google's NCR link

Tags: google-chrome, search

I work out of London office and my office in all its wisdom has the proxy in Germany which means whenever I type something in Chrome's omnibox, it does the search via http://www.google.de instead of www.google.co.uk.

**Question**

How can I change it to use google.com/ncr

**What I have tried**

I have tried to update settings in Chrome as follows but even then it does not work.

[image]

Comment: Note: Advising to change the default search to Bing is a strict No-No!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not working because you haven't edited `[google:baseURL]`.

Use this string

```
https://www.google.com/search?q=%s
```

EDIT: See comments

Comment: Thanks! But I am not able to edit [google:baseURL] field in Chrome. It is Read Only.

Comment: You can create another Search Engine String and make it default.

Comment: Brilliant! Worked like a charm!

Comment: This doesn't work for me, but I'm not completely clear on the exact steps required.

Comment: @sbwoodside: Go to chrome://settings > Click on Manage Search Engines and the add the relevant details in the empty textboxes in the bottom.

Answer (score 4):

*Edit Sept 2015: This doesn't seem to work any more.*

There's a better way. If you edit the search string in the Preferences, you won't get autofill results. If you do it this way, you will.

Change Chrome's Search Engine to Google.com:
http://googlesystem.blogspot.ca/2013/07/change-chromes-search-engine-to.html

1. Type google.com/ncr in the address bar and search for something
2. Close Chrome
3. Launch Chrome again, open a new tab and search for something using Chrome's omnibox.
4. You should see an infobar that asks you: "would you like to search with google.com instead of [your local Google domain]?"

Comment: Thank you. This almost looks like dark magic. I couldn't convince Chrome to use google.com while still providing suggestions until I found your answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work any more.

Comment: @skolima: agreed, doesn't seem to work now.

Comment: This worked for me!

Comment: @AmmarAbdulaziz I can't reproduce. What version are you running, what OS, what country are you in, and are you logged into google?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the URL provided in the answer marked as correct has limited functionality. Specifically, user may find it does not trigger search suggestions, etc.

<del>So here's an answer to solve that, which also provides more comprehensive instructions for those who are not familiar with such things.</del>

*UPDATE* My intent was to post a URL that was reported elsewhere to provide auto-suggestions *and* force the omnibar to `google.com` domain. But I have now found none of the suggested URLs provide auto-suggestions. I will, however, leave the below instructions, as they may come in useful for people who want detailed info on how to add a new entry to the omnibar search, for locking in `google.com` domain.

There is also a better option below, using an extension.

1. Bring up Google Chrome `Setting`s (`Preferences` on MacOS, acccessed easily with `COMMAND-comma`)
2. In the *Search* section, click `Manage search engines...`

[image: Manage search engines button]

3. Scroll down the list of `Other search engines` to the bottom. You'll see the option to `Add a new search engine`

[image: Add search engine]

4. Call it something like `Google NCR`, or anything that makes sense to you. I suggest not calling it `Google` in order to avoid possible confusion later.
5. Use the following URL:
   <del>https://www.google.com/search?q=%s{google:assistedQueryStats}{google:searchFieldtrialParameter}{google:bookmarkBarPinned}{google:searchClient}{google:sourceId}{google:instantExtendedEnabledParameter}{google:omniboxStartMarginParameter}{google:contextualSearchVersion}ie={inputEncoding}</del>

The above link was **meant** to provide search suggestions too. But it doesn't. So you can just use the simple URL mentioned in other answers, namely, `https://google.com/search?q=%s`

6. Once you've added the new search option, you'll need to locate it in the list of `Other search engines` and hover your mouse over it, then select `Make default`

[image: Make default]

(In the above image the mouse is hovering over the first engine option in the list, just for illustration purposes)

That's it. Should be done.

### A better option to force NCR (no country redirect) in the omnibar, with auto-suggestions

There is a Chrome Extension that does exactly what's required. It will force the domain to `google.com` and all other omnibar functionality will continue to work (such as auto-suggesions, etc.) It's available [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/omnibox-ncr).

Answer (score -1):

I've found a new way and it is relatively simple.

1. Go to your google.com.?? page.
2. Click on the link on the lower right corner that says use www.google.com
3. Do a search not from the Omnnibox but from the search bar in the page.
4. Do another search but now from the omnibox.

As soon as you do so, you will see a message asking if you want to use www.google.com as your default search engine or not. Choose google.com and you're done!